# Predictions become irrational after adding weights to the fit

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, training-data, weighted

I have a model with several dense layers that behaves normally in all aspects.

Then, I add weights to the training events (their values are between 0 and 1):

```
w = mydata.Weight
#...
kfold = GroupKFold(n_splits=num_folds)
for train, test in kfold.split(X, y, groups=groups):
    X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train], X.iloc[test]
    y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train], y.iloc[test]
    w_train = w.iloc[train]
#...
    le_fit = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=200, epochs=10, sample_weight=w_train, verbose=0)
#...
    predictions = np.rint(model.predict(X_test))
```

and the prediction becomes useless:

```
InvalidArgumentError: `predictions` contains negative values
Condition x >= 0 did not hold element-wise:
x (confusion_matrix_1/Cast:0) = 
[-9223372036854775808 .......
```

Just to be safe, I added constraints in the layers, eg:

```
layers.Dense(units=800, activation='relu', kernel_constraint=constraints.MinMaxNorm(min_value=0.0, max_value=1.0))
```

but nothing changed.

Can you suggest what is going wrong?

Edit: I now realized that the training loss is also a nan.

Edit: I made all weights equal to one. The results don't change.

Edit: I don't know why this question was closed as asking for debugging. The answer makes it obvious that it wasn't about debugging. It is about the correct usage of two very commonly used items (Keras with GroupKFold), which turns out to include a counter-intuitive element, and it is not problem-specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `sample_weight` takes np.array as input, but `w_train` was an ndarray.

It was solved by creating explicitly an array:

```
w_train_tmp = w.iloc[train]
w_train = np.array(w_train_tmp)
```

Note: I know that np.array and ndarray are technically the same thing. If someone can clarify why they weren't in this case, you are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to print the samples and see if there is any wrong sample.
In addition, I would try to add normalization between the layers or try with simpler data (like generating fictive data you think your machine should definitely learn and predict and check if your machine is learning something or not).

Comment: The model was extensively tested and used before adding the weights. Everything else about it and about the data was running normally. I think that this points to a problem with the implementation of the weights.